# Comparing Non-duplicate File Content Format of two files in Python

Tags: python, file, csv, format, comparison

I am wondering if there is a way to compare the file content format of comma separated value (csv) files in python. I have a script that takes in an input csv file and gives generated output. I tried running the script on a given set of files, but got an error message with the files I was given. To test if the script was the issue, I ran the script using a different set of files with the same format, which worked. This leads me to believe that the one of the files is formatted incorrectly. I tried checking for formatting visually, but there are too many columns and rows to check for formatting issues and column data types.

An example:

File_1.csv content contains:

```
Field_1,Field_2,Field_3, Field_4, ...
ABC, 2012, CH4, 31231.123, ...
ABC2, 20134, H20, 3234.3432, ...
..., ..., ..., ..., ...
```

File_2.csv content contains:

```
Field_1, Field_2, Field_3, Field_4, ...
BBC, 324, OH, 323.232, ...
BBC2, 2112, HCL, 23.2324, ...
..., ..., ..., ..., ...
```

The idea would be two use the formatting of file_1.csv to make sure file_2.csv has the same format and data types. It would essentially check if file two is following the same format as file one:

```
<Str>, <Str>, <Str>, <Str>, ...
<Str>, <int>, <Char>, <float>, ...
<Str>, <int>, <Char>, <float>, ...
<Str>, <int>, <Char>, <float>, ...
```

Assuming that File one has correct column name format and row data types. Is there a program/script has been written that compares file format and data types? Or, would I have to do this from scratch?

Comment: _I tried running the script on a given set of files, but got an error message_ Did the error message give any clues as to what the exact error was?

Comment: Hi there @JohnGordon, I was able to figure out the how to write it. I did encounter an issue with regex pattern matching if you want to take a look at Mauricio Martinez question/post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this yourself pretty quick. I'm assuming you're getting an error while trying to type cast one of the fields to an int/char or something. You can use a try-except statement to try and pin-point the error. Here's some pseudo code:

```
for line in file:
    # separate the fields
    fields  = line.split(',')
    try:
        field1 = int(fields[0])
    except:
        # you had an error
```

Obviously if you have a lot of fields this could be tedious, but I'm assuming you already have something like this written in your code.

Comment: Hi there @MauricioMartinez, I understand the line.split(',') in the code above. I tried an implementation of it. However, I encountered an issue with  **`re.split(r',(?![^"]")',content1.iloc[0][0]))`**. I tried using a look ahead to avoid commas in double quotes like the following: **`,"1,4-Benzenediol; Hydroquinol; p-Quinol",`** I works for the following **',"2,6-Diamino-4-hexenoic acid, 9CI",'**, but not the latter. Any help would be much appreciated. I am positive I did not write the look ahead regex correctly, and trying to figure it out.